# ANDROID - How to Seperate JSONObject value from sqlite field

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I've an `sqlite` in android, and the structure of `sqlite` is like :

```
|---------|-------------------|
|  id     | name (BLOB type)  |
|   1     | jsonObject value  |
|   2     | jsonObject value  |
|---------|-------------------|
```

sample value of `jsonobject value` is :

```
{"AuditScheduleDetailID":12422,"AuditAnswerId":3,"LocalFindingID":9,"LocalMediaID":18,"Files":"xxx","ExtFiles":"jpg"}
```

the problem :

is it possible to separate those `jsonobject value` when I want to display it in `listview` or `log`?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray Obj;
Obj = your value get from sqlite.
if (Obj != null)
{
try {
     for (int j = 0; j < Obj.length(); j++)
     {
      JSONObject jsonObject = Obj.getJSONObject(j);
      String AuditScheduleDetailID= 
      jsonObject.optString("AuditScheduleDetailID");
      // etc ...your other values

    }     
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

According to link :

```
  for (Contact cn : contacts)
  {
  String AuditScheduleDetailID=cn.getID();
  String Name= cn.getName();
  }
```

Comment: when i tried ur code above, I've an error when i use `Obj=db.getAllContact();` that android studio tell me to use `Obj=(JSONArray) db.getAllContact()` but that code giving me an error `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray`

Comment: no you can do like this
   Obj ="{"AuditScheduleDetailID":12422,"AuditAnswerId":3,"LocalFindingID":9,"LocalMediaID":18,"Files":"xxx","ExtFiles":"jpg"}"
otherwise show full code.

Comment: about the full code, I'm refer to [this link](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) and the type data of `your value get from sqlite` is a `String` not an `JsonArray`

Answer (score 0):

you can store `JsonObject` as string and retrieve using `Cursor` and convert `String` into `JsonObject`

```
JsonObject j= new JsonObject(cursor.getString("",""));
String s=j.getString("find_your _param");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store your data as json objects inside database columns, you will lose some features like querying more efficiently by the fields inside that json object. For example, selecting by id=1 gets you a json object or json array `{'foo':'bar'}` but you can't efficiently select every tuple which has foo=bar.

You can design your database to accept columns according to the json object fields. e.g. "AuditScheduleDetailID" is a column (etc).

Sometimes the json data can not be easily mapped to columns in a single table (like when you have completely different json objects). 
The simple solution is to store them in files and organizing them in folders.

For answering your question, I recommend using a json serializer/parser like google gson. It is used to convert the string retrieved from your database (the `name` field) to the appropriate class (like `Contact`). Unless your data in `name` column are completely various (like Contact class and Person class and Car class) you will have objects with properties filled by Gson. If the variety is included, you need to reconsider your design and move unrelated objects to another table. Like having a `Contact` table, a `Person` table etc.

Gson's documentation is [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2). A simple example would be:

```
Contact c = new Gson().fromJson(YOUR_JSON_OBJECT_STRING, Contact.class);
```